# In Linux, how can I merge the output of two console commands into a text file?

Tags: linux

I'm obtaining the first line and last 10,000 lines of a csv as follows:

```
head workrace.csv -n 1
tail workrace.csv -n 10000
```

How can I merge the output into a single text file?  I can pipe the above commands into two separate text files and then concatenate the files.  Is there a way to do this without needing to use intermediary text files?

Comment: You cannot pipe commands to a file.  You can redirect the output of a command to a file, or you can pipe the output to another process, but you cannot pipe output to a file.  You can only pipe output to a pipe.  (Technically, a pipe is a file, but you cannot pipe output to a regular file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either run both commands in a subshell:

```
( head workrace.csv -n 1 ; tail workrace.csv -n 10000 ) > result.txt
```

or, you can use the `>>` redirection operator to add contents to a file:

```
head workrace.csv -n 1      > result.txt
tail workrace.csv -n 10000 >> result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other options not mentioned by choroba:

```
F=workrace.c
{ head -n 1 $F; tail -n 10000 $F; } > result.txt  # no subshell
awk 'NR==1 || NR>k-1000' k="$( wc -l < $F )" $F > result.txt
exec > result.txt   # truncate result.txt and direct output of remaining commands to it
head -n 1 $F
tail -n 10000 $F
```